# Can I get the current state of a twitter bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I currently call a script to dynamically add content to my popover but I don't need to make this call when a user clicks again to close it.  Is it possible to get the state and close it when it's visible?

This is what I have so far:

```
$('.knownissue').on('click', function() {

    var info = $(this).attr('id').substr(5).split(':');
    var el = $(this);

    // How do I check to see if the popover is visible
    // so I can simply close it and exit?

    $.post('functions/get_known_issues.php?tcid='+info[0]+'&tcdate=' + info[1], function(data) {
        if (data.st) {
            el.attr('data-content', data.issue);
            el.popover('toggle');
        }
    }, "json");

});
```

Comment: You may find a clue if you look at [how the plugin checks it (github)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.2.1/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js#L240)

Answer (score 7):

To avoid searching for dynamically inserted markup you can do this:

In Bootstrap 2:

```
var $element = $('.element-you-added-popup-to')
$element.data().popover.tip().hasClass('in')
// Or if you used '.tooltip()' instead of '.popover()'
$element.data().tooltip.tip().hasClass('in')
```

In Bootstrap 3:

```
$element.data()['bs.popover'].tip().hasClass('in')
$element.data()['bs.tooltip'].tip().hasClass('in')
```

Comment: Caused Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popover' of undefined in Chrome 45. Fixed via

$element.data()['bs.popover'].tip().hasClass('in')

Answer (score 6):

```
if($('.popover').hasClass('in')){
  // popover is visable
} else {
  // popover is not visable
}
```

Comment: You can have many popovers, it will fail if some other popover is shown.

Answer (score 2):

the hidden and shown events are available in bootstrap popover as default.

```html
$('#myPopover').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

The Following events for bootstrap popover are available

```html
show.bs.popover 
shown.bs.popover
hide.bs.popover 
hidden.bs.popover
```

Please Refer to docs [bootstrap popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) for more details

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 4.x

```
 $('a#aUeberschriftenJBi').click(function() {
    if ($('a#aUeberschriftenJBi').attr('aria-describedby')) {
        // popover is visable
    } else {
        // popover is not visable
        $('a#aUeberschriftenJBi').popover({
            placement: 'bottom',
            title: function() {
                return "Title";
            },
            content: function() {
                return "Content";
            }
        });
    }

    $('a#aUeberschriftenJBi').popover("show");
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="aUeberschriftenJBi" title=""><span><i class="fa fa-sticky-note"></i></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap adds and removes the markup for the popover dynamically, so you just need to check for the existence of the element.

If you go to the Bootstrap example page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers, you can toggle their example popover with the large red button displayed there that says "Click to toggle popover"

This jquery selector is written to select that popover element if it exists
    $('#popovers').find('h3').eq(5).next().find('.popover')

To check it's state (exists or not), check if the length of returned element set is 0.

So push the button to toggle their popover example, then run the following in the console:

TOGGLE POPOVER ON

```
console.log( 
     $('#popovers').find('h3').eq(5).next().find('.popover').length === 0
); // false
```

TOGGLE POPOVER OFF

```
console.log( 
    $('#popovers').find('h3').eq(5).next().find('.popover').length === 0
); // true
```

PS - Hopefully you'll write a better selector since you already know you're going to need to check the popover exists on the page or not

EDIT : [link to jsfiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eLjQG/7/)

Comment: I guess I don't see how that will work.  I check for the existence of the element and it returns 0 for both toggle states...

Comment: Go here and click the popup: http://jsfiddle.net/eLjQG/7/
I switched the conditional to check that the length is not equal so it alerts true when it's open, false when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($('#elementId').attr('aria-describedby')) {
  alert('Popover is Visible');
  $("#elementId").popover('hide'); // To Hide Popover

}else{
  alert('Popover is Hidden');
  $("#elementId").popover('show'); // To Display Popover
}
```